# Log output from unrar.exe to a text file (Batch script)

Tags: batch-file, unrar

I am writing a batch script that extracts files and would now like to log the output from unrar.exe to a text file. The output I have in mind are things like failure due to corrupted archives etc. or simply that the operation was successful.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use redirection:

```
unrar > logfile.txt
```

To also redirect stderr:

```
unrar > logfile.txt 2>&1
```

Comment: Thx! I end up with a empty text file though =(

Comment: I got the empty file because of the command START I think. My bad!

Answer (score 1):

Just the STDOUT

`unrar>"output.txt"`

Only the errors (ERROUT)

`unrar 2>"errors.txt"`

Both STDOUT and ERROUT

`unrar 2>&1 "both.txt"`

Or both in separate files:

`unrar 2>"errors.txt" >"output.txt"`